# Match all non-python files in /dir

Tags: cmake, glob

Whit globbing expressions on cmake, `/dir/*.py`  - match all python files in `/dir`

But how I do the opposit? Match all non-py files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all files and then remove the the python files, i.e.:

```
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE _pythonFiles
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir/*.py")
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE _nonPythonFiles 
    RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir/*.*")
list(REMOVE_ITEM _nonPythonFiles ${_pythonFiles})
```